# Unable to associate the Amazon Load Balancer with a subdomain on Cloudflare

Tags: dns, cloudflare, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have the Amazon Load Balancer. I tried to make one of my subdomains redirect requests to the load balancer. Following this [doc (point Amazon ELB (Elastic Load Balancing))](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020991331) I've created a new CNAME record in my domain on Cloudflare:

- Type: CNAME
- Name: api
- Target: xxx.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com
- TTL: auto
- Proxy status: DNS only

[image]

I waited >24 hours and I still get nothing on api.mydomain.com. I checked 3 addresses and got:

Check the load balancer (OK):

```
$ nslookup xxx.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com

Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   xxx.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 3.xx.xx.255
Name:   xxx.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 3.xx.xx.165
```

Check the main domain (OK):

```
$ nslookup mydomain.com

Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mydomain.com
Address: 108.xx.xx.71
```

Check the new subdomain (NOTHING):

```
$ nslookup api.mydomain.com

Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

** server can't find api.mydomain.com: NXDOMAIN
```

**Questions:**

1. Should I do an additional setup to make it work?
2. Why does `nslookup api.mydomain.com` return nothing? Doesn't it look like the subdomain wasn't created, so the problem isn't the connection between the load balancer and Cloudflare, but that Cloudflare hasn't created the subdomain?
3. By the [link (point AWS nameserver updates)](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020991331) I can find the instruction for adding nameserver records to Route 53, but I cannot find any info on how it helps me. I've replaced the default NS records of the domain on "Hosted zones" (AWS) with the two NS records from my Cloudflare domain, but no effect. Do I need to configure Route 53 to make the load balancer work with Cloudflare (I don't use Route 53 for anything)?
4. I've enabled the "Flexible" SSL/TLS encryption mode on Cloudflare. I need the Flexible encryption for the main domain and don't need it for the subdomains, because they have their own SSL. Can this affect the problem?

Comment: You're absolutely right in that NXDOMAIN means it not being resolved at all - So it's like cloudflare hasn't not propagated it yet. SSL/TLS has nothing to do with this issue. However, an interesting point you mentioned is Route 53 and NS - can you share more on the setup you have between Cloudflare and NS? You would usually use one CDN or the other. So is your domain configured entirely with Cloudflare? There are cases where you need to split DNS management between two providers and that's where NS comes in the picture.

Comment: Regarding Route 53 setup. I just tried to set it up in case if the AWS ELB needs an additional setup to accept a connection to my Cloudflare configured domain (I'm not sure if I need that). **What I did:** (**a**) created the Hosted zone "mydomain.com" on AWS; (**b**) copied the 2 nameservers (xxx.ns.cloudflare.com) from the domain page on Cloudflare (DNS tab -> NS records); (**c**) replaced the 4 existing nameservers of the newly created Hosted zone (ns-xxx.awsdns-xx.xxx) on AWS with the 2 copied nameservers from Cloudflare.

Comment: @KedMardemootoo Thank you for your attention, but the problem was in carelessness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in poorly performed migration from OVH to Cloudflare by a previous developer. I'm putting here the way that helped me to find the root of the cause in case if it will help someone else.

What I did:

1. I checked the subdomain `api.mydomain.com` and saw the response `Status: NXDOMAIN`. But if I have correctly set up the CNAME to the AWS ELB as grey-clouded (DNS-only), I should get amazon IPs back from the resolver. Checker: http://dig.ping.pe/api.mydomain.com:NS:1.1.1.1
2. I checked the NS records of my domain and realized they are pointing to OVH and not on Cloudflare. Checker: http://dig.ping.pe/mydomain.com:NS:1.1.1.1
3. To make it work on Cloudflare, I have to visit the domain registrar and change the NS: [Changing your domain nameservers to Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205195708-Changing-your-domain-nameservers-to-Cloudflare)

Answering my own questions:

1. Should I do an additional setup to make it work?
   **Nope. Adding the CNAME record is enough.**
2. Why does `nslookup api.mydomain.com` return nothing?
   **Because the subdomain wasn't created.**
3. Do I need to configure Route 53 to make the load balancer work with Cloudflare?
   **No, you don't need it.**
4. Can SSL/TLS affect the problem?
   **No**